# Retain dynamically submitted select options on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, form-submit

I have an html form with a dynamically populated select:

```
    <form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="beforeSubmit()" id="crypto_form">
        <textarea name="message" id="textarea_message" oninput="this.value.toUpperCase()" cols="60" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
        <select form="crypto_form" name="keydata" id="select_keydata"></select>
        <button type="submit" name="type" id="btn_encrypt" value="encrypt">Encrypt</button>
        <button type="submit" name="type" id="btn_decrypt" value="decrypt">Decrypt</button>
    </form>
```

The problem is that when I submit the form, all select values disappear. How do I retain them when I submit the form? I looked at similar questions to this, but none of them solve my particular case.

What I believe is happening is that the page is reloading and that's why the options are disappearing.

I'm using golang as a backend with `net/http`. Although, I don't think it has much linking here, but let me know if it helps in solving the problem.

**Note: The `beforeSubmit()` function is empty. Anything I can put in there to retain the options?**

Comment: Hard to answer with the information you are giving. Is the whole page refreshing after the submit? When select values disappear? After or before the submit?

Comment: @f-CJ Yes. I would believe so. I don't think the options would disappear otherwise.

Comment: Well, if the website is refreshing... you could use localstorage to store the options and use them after refresh or you could store  the options created dynamically in the backend and request when the page is loaded.

Comment: @f-CJ yup, found it after a little more digging! Was just about to post an answer. Thanks though! You wanna do the honours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the website is refreshing, you could use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` in order to save your data in the browser.

**It is recommended to use ES6 Maps for storing `<option>` values. The map can then be converted to a JSON string and stored in your `localStorage/sessionStorage`.**

Here's a snippet adding `<option>` text and value to a map:

```
map.set(option.text, option.value)
```

So your `beforeSubmit()` function would look like this:

```
function beforeSubmit() {
    sessionStorage.myMap = JSON.stringify(Array.from(map));
};
```

And when you want to retrieve the data, say, in `window.onload` you can do it as follows:

```
var map;

window.onload = function() {
    if (sessionStorage.myMap != null) {
        map = new Map(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.myMap));
    } else {
        map = new Map();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this code :

```
type="submit"
```

to 
    `type="button"`

```
 <button type="button" name="type" id="btn_encrypt" value="encrypt">Encrypt</button>
 <button type="button" name="type" id="btn_decrypt" value="decrypt">Decrypt</button>
```

Comment: And then submit the form via javascript?